# Display product OR collection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, distinct

I'm doing a products system where a product can be included inside a collection.

In products' page I show all the products, BUT if some product is INSIDE a collection, I need to display only the collection name and NOT the product itself. I mean, hide the products who are inside a collection *and* show the collection *once* while also showing the others products (without collection).

TABLE 1: colecciones ("collections" in Spanish) - 
Where I store the ID and name of the collection.

```
CREATE TABLE `colecciones` ( 
  `id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
  `nombre` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `colecciones`
    (`nombre`)
VALUES
  ('dulce'),('salado'),('agrio')
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8534e/1/0

TABLE 2: productos ("products") -
Where I store the products and, if it is inside a collection, the collection ID (column "coleccion"). If not, the value is 0.

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` ( 
  `id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
 `nombre` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
 `coleccion` INT(255) NOT NULL , 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `productos`
    (`nombre`, `coleccion`)
VALUES
  ('manzana',1),('salmon',2),('sandia',0),('sopa',3),('pera',1),('agua',0)
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6aef2/1/0

Looking at the example, the product with name "manzana" (apple) is part of collection "dulce" (sweet), and the product "agua" (water) isn't part of any collection.

What I expect to show is this:

```
<h1>My products</h1>

dulce /* (ID 1 table `colecciones`) because I have products with "coleccion = 1" */
salado /* (ID 2 table `colecciones`) because I have products with "coleccion = 2" */
sandia /* the product itself, not collection */
agrio /* (ID 3 table `colecciones`) because I have products with "coleccion = 3" */
agua /* the product itself, not collection */
```

I'm stuck with this. How can I display the data in this way with PHP?

I need to order like `productos.id DESC`, which I accomplished by adding at the end:

```
ORDER BY c.`id` DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an aggregation will do what you want:

```
select (case when c.name is not null then c.name else p.name end) as name
from productos p left join
     colecciones c
     on p.coleccion = c.id
group by name, (c.name is not null);
```

The second condition in the `group by` just ensures that you get two rows when the product and coleccion have the same name.

I also think this will work for your purposes:

```
select p.name from productos where coleccion = 0
union all
select c.name from colecciones;
```

You seem to want all products not in a collection plus the collection names (which is what this query does).

EDIT:

I'm not sure which id you want, but you could do:

```
select p.name, p.id from productos where coleccion = 0
union all
select c.name, c.id from colecciones
order by id desc;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. The first query is totally useful for me, thanks a lot! Please, help me to understand; why are there some letters (c on "c.name", "productos p", "colecciones c", etc.)?

Comment: Now the thing is the products are showing like "ORDER BY productos.nombre ASC" but I need "ORDER BY productos.id DESC" (the latest products are displayed before).

Comment: @JimmyAdaro . . . This doesn't return the products in any particular order at all.  You question doesn't mention the order.

Comment: Well, that's right. Is there any chance to order by "id desc" that query?

Comment: @JimmyAdaro The letters `c` and `p` represent the so called MySQL aliases (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html). Basically `collecciones c` is shorthand for `colleciones AS c` where you can use the letter `c` in any part of the query to reference the table `colecciones`.

Comment: Hey @holodoc thanks for the explanation! That affects to the query speed, right?

Comment: @JimmyAdaro No, aliases do not affect performance in any way that is even remotely measurable. Their main role is to provide syntactical convenience and prevent ambiguity.

Comment: @holodoc Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the order doesn't matter, just use two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE coleccion = 0;
```

This will give you all the products that are not in a collection.  Although, I would suggest using `NULL` instead of `0`.

Second query:

```
SELECT colecciones.* FROM productos
INNER JOIN colecciones on colecciones.id = productos.coleccion
GROUP BY coleccion;
```

This will give you all of the collections that have products.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen.

When I execute the second query in PHPMyAdmin, I get this error:

"#1146 - Table 'mytable.colecciones' doesn't exist"

What could be the problem?

Comment: It means that table does not exist in the selected database.

Comment: That was a typo. The real name is `mytable.productos_colecciones`, the `mytable.colecciones` was for example.